# Changing terminal prompt in `tcsh`

Tags: tcsh

My terminal shell prompt defaults to `[johnnine@tec ~]$`.

How should I use "set prompt" in `~/.cshrc`, so that it also displays time?

Comment: by reading some [documentation](https://nature.berkeley.edu/~casterln/tcsh/Special_shell_variables.html#prompt)

Comment: .. and more specifically, look up the `prompt` [section](https://nature.berkeley.edu/~casterln/tcsh/Special_shell_variables.html#prompt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You now presumably have : `set prompt="[%n@%M %~]$ "`.

You can change it to anything you fancy adding/inserting `%p`for time in 12 hour format or `%P` for the same in 24-hour format.

Place this in you `~/.cshrc` file and after each modification, source the file to enable the tentative changes and see if the results is what you expect.  To source  just enter `$ source ~/.cshrc` in terminal.